# How is the core data file stored / accessed by the app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm currently working for a company that white-label's our app & I'm working on the core data functionality. Do I need to update the prefix-name of the .xcdatamodel file so it's different for each white-labeled app? I don't want stored data to appear in the wrong app.

Comment: I don't know the technical definition of "white-label" but....  If you're talking about different apps, then each has its own sandbox, therefore unique data storage.  (Jailbreak is a different subject.)

Comment: @PhillipMills That assumes iOS but OP didn’t specify.

Comment: @PhillipMills what I mean by white-label, is having an main app as a foundation (that isn't used for production), and then each subsequent app we produce is "re-skinned" for each individual client. Thus, fundamentally it'll look & be used exactly the same, however different image / color assets are used to "differentiate" each app. [Here is the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product)

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I tagged swift in the question to try to prevent the ambiguity.

Comment: Uniqueness in an iOS app is mostly a function of the bundle identifier and provisioning information.  Can you describe a case that you're concerned about protecting against?

Comment: @PhillipMills I have a main branch that acts as the foundation for each of the white-labeled apps. I'm currently working on the core-data functionality here; so what I'm afraid is, if i merge this branch with the customer-branch and a user has two of our apps, that the data stored in core data would be shared across these apps. but apparently it seems taht I won't run into this issue according to what you said. So thank you for clarifying this up for me!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use the same name as your target white-label, so yes prefix the xcdatamodel with the company you are targeting. So if a white-label company is called "abc" then you should consider prefixing the data as "abc.xcdatamodel". This is what we did when we were targeting customers hope this helps.